# map and query on multidimensional array in elasticsearch

Tags: multidimensional-array, elasticsearch

I'm very newbie to ElasticSearch. This is how my data looks like.how can I map and query on the following data.

```
[parameters] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [param_id] => "Browser"
                [param_values] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "Firefox"
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [param_id] => "BrowserVersion"
                [param_values] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "39"
                    )
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [param_id] => "OS"
                [param_values] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "Windows"
                    )
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [param_id] => "Softwares"
                [param_values] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "Java"
                        [1] => "Oracle"
                        [2] => "PHP"
                    )
            )
    )
```

I have to get the results of the following query.

The Users which are using "OS" as "Windows" and "Softwares" as "Java". How to map these data and query?

Below is the Mapping JSON:

```
{
"response": {
  "properties": {
    "profile_id" : {"type" : "long"},
    "timestamp" : {"type" : "string"},
    "parameters" : {
        "type": "nested",
      "properties":{
        "param_id":{"type": "string"},
        "param_values": {             
              "type": "string"                                            
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Below is my Query JSON:

```
{   "query": {
  "filtered": {
     "query": {
        "match_all": {}
     },
     "filter": {
        "bool": {
           "must": [
              {
                 "nested": {
                    "path": "parameters",
                    "query": {
                       "bool": {
                          "must": [
                             {
                                "term": {
                                   "parameters.param_id": "Softwares"
                                }
                             },
                             {
                                "term": {
                                   "parameters.param_values": "Java"
                                }
                             }
                          ]
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }   }}
```

Comment: Could you post it in JSON format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's start off by creating the index using

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/responses -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "response": {
      "properties": {
        "profile_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "param_id": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "param_values": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And then we index your sample document:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/responses/response/1 -d '{
  "profile_id": 1,
  "timestamp": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "param_id": "Browser",
      "param_values": [
        "Firefox"
      ]
    },
    {
      "param_id": "BrowserVersion",
      "param_values": [
        "39"
      ]
    },
    {
      "param_id": "OS",
      "param_values": [
        "Windows"
      ]
    },
    {
      "param_id": "Softwares",
      "param_values": [
        "Java",
        "Oracle",
        "PHP"
      ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

You've started off very well and your query is almost correct. If you want to query for users who are using "Windows" as "OS" and "Java" as "Softwares", you already have the constraint on the latter, now you just need one more contraint for the former (i.e. `OS=Windows`)

```
{
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "parameters",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "parameters.param_id": "os"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "parameters.param_values": "windows"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "parameters",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "parameters.param_id": "softwares"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "parameters.param_values": "java"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That's not giving the desired result. The above query was working fine when there are only 1 element in "param_values" field. If there are multiple values like "Softwares" It's not working as expected. If I run the query with only OS=windows it was working fine.

Comment: Your comment doesn't seem like it was completed.

Comment: Is it working for you? I'm not able to get the result. I'll check once by deleting and creating the index again.

Comment: Yes, that's working for me, try again by doing the steps I gave and let me know.

Comment: Thanks Val, It's working fine for me also. But is it necessary to convert the querying values to lower case? If I enter with the capital letters It's not returning results. Only lower case values are returning results. How can I avoid this case sensitive issue?

Comment: Yes, it's because the `param_id` and `param_values` properties are `analyzed`. if you don't want this, you simply need to change your mapping and add `"index": "not_analyzed"` to those fields. Don't forget to re-index your data afterwards.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Val, But It's not working with lower case now. Is there any change in the mapping, so that I can filter with both Lower and upper case? And also how can I fetch all the matched records? by default I can able to fetch only 10 records.

Comment: If you added `not_analyzed` then your search must be case-sensitive (like in your question). To show more than 10 results, use the `"size"` parameter (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks for your help Val. Working fine. How many indices we can have maximum.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Do you mean in the whole ES cluster?

Comment: yes, I want to create a index for each customer. I can have a maximum of 10,000 customers. each customer can have millions of users. all my search and aggregations are happened on the users of respective customer. Is it a good idea to create separate index for each customer?

Comment: If you have 10K customers I'd say it's **not** a good idea to create one index for each. But without knowing more about your data, I can't really say more, except that you should probably look into [routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) and [aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html).

Comment: What do you think the maximum indexes we can have? any suggestions, so that I can club 10 to 50 customers into a single index.

Comment: It depends on many, many, many factors. Your hardware (RAM, Disk, CPU, etc), your document size, etc. I suggest [reading how wordpress.com](http://gibrown.com/2014/01/09/scaling-elasticsearch-part-1-overview) did to index the billion documents they have. That's an interesting read.